# Append/dump dataframe to json file

Tags: python, json, dataframe, append, dump

I'm trying to append parts of a dataframe to a json file in order to efficiently store new data in already existing files. I tried the following (and many other things), but this does not lead to a nicely readable json file..

```
for i in [1,2,3]:
  for j in [1,2,3]:
    df_part = df.query(f'(A == {i}) & (B == {j})')
    with open(f'json_file_{i}.csv','a+') as json_file:
      json.dump(df_part.to_dict(),json_file)
```

How can I efficiently add/append/dump data from a dataframe to a certain file (perferably json)?

Thanks!

Comment: your df.query is missing a closing `'`

Comment: ah yeah true thanks, but that's not what's causing my problem

Comment: well for sure it was, since the code before was not executable.

Answer (score 0):

try doing the dump before your writting

```
json_string = json.dumps(your_data)

with open('destinationFile.json', 'a') as outfile:
    outfile.write(json_string)
```

Comment: with the 'your_data' being a dataframe? leads to TypeError: Object of type DataFrame is not JSON serializable. With being a dict leads to many dicts below each other ignoring that there are columns which are the same in each dict..

Comment: could you please provide some example of your data